# DataGrid - Binding double array to column

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, binding, datagrid

In my DataGrid I have three columns, number of rows is dynamic. The values for the DataGrid are double arrays. How can I bind each array to his column without creating a new class (I've propertychangedevent on each array)

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" 
                              CellEditEnding="dataGrid_Kennlinie_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="dataGrid_Kennlinie_BeginningEdit"
                              MaxWidth="500">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="nue" Binding="{Binding nue}" Width="*">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="mue" Binding="{Binding mue}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="tpc[Nm]" Binding="{Binding MPc}" Width="*" />
....end
```

nue, mue and MPc are arrays inbetween another class. When I just do

```
dataGrid.ItemSource = class.nue;
```

In this class I create the class which includes my needed variables, these are:

```
private double[] _nue;
    public double[] nue
    {
        get { return _nue; }
        set
        {
            if (_nue == value) return;
            _nue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_nue");
        }
    }
    private double[] _mue;
    public double[] mue
    {
        get { return _mue; }
        set
        {
            if (_mue == value) return;
            _mue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_mue");
        }
    }
    private double[] _MPc;
    public double[] MPc
    {
        get { return _MPc; }
        set
        {
            if (_MPc == value) return;
            _MPc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("_MPc");
        }
    }
```

it sets me the correct number of rows but without values.

Any ideas?
Thanks and happy new year

Comment: You should put the code for the class that you use as data source.

Comment: I don't need the whole class, just three variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you a just binding to one array (`nue`). 
Thus the amount of rows is correct, but no data is shown. Because `nue.nue, nue.mue` etc does not exist. (You should see errors about the missing bindings in the output window.)

The easiest solution would be to restructure your class, and bind an List, Array or ObervableCollection of that class.

If you get the double arrays as input from somewhere: there is no way around to map this data in some other structure, that the DataGrid can handle by default.

```
// simplified
class Container {
  public double Nue {get; set;}
  public double Mue {get; set;}
  public double MPc {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
ObservableCollection<Container> containers = ...
dataGrid.ItemSource = containers;
```

---

```
// This will now update the grid, just like other operations on the ObservableCollection
containers.Add(new Container {
   Nue = 13.1,
   Mue = 2.23,
   MPc = 0.01
});
```

The DataGrid xaml can stay as is, the Bindings should work now.

Comment: but then I do not have my propertychanged event on the originals, I just write new variables with the values of my needed ones

Comment: Container could implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you can raise OnPropertyChanged on it's properties.

Comment: but then there are doubles.. So when I raise an event, it only changes the double value, not the whole array

Comment: This is correct. But since it's an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) it will updated on Added and Removed values.

Comment: Yes binding works, but it is how I said, just "copying" the values I need, but not raising the event to change the arrays